# Pushing picture to gitlab with python-gitlab

Tags: python, json, utf-8, gitlab, python-gitlab

I am trying to push a jpg picture to a gitlab repo with `python-gitlab`. My code looks like

```py
gl = gitlab.Gitlab(GITLAB_URL, PRIVATE_TOKEN)
project = gl.projects.get(PROJECT_ID)

with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
  file_content = f.read()

branch = project.branches.get('main')

project.files.create(
  {
    'file_path': f"{REPOSITORY_PATH}/{PATH_IN_REPO}",
    'branch': branch.name,
    'content': file_content,
    'commit_message': commit_message
  }
)
```

With (hopefully) obvious meaning of the variables. I am getting an error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

that I suspect is related to the way I am opening the jpg file. Hints?

Comment: You are reading the file content in binary mode ('rb') but the client library expects string data. You should try to encode it as a sting or read the file in text mode

Comment: So something like `file_content.encode("base64")` and later in the json passing `encoding: base64` ?